# How to retrieve all the documents in couchdb by given key?

Tags: couchdb

Our couch DB url is http://10.1.5.88:5984/_utils/database.html?testdata/

I want to retrieve all the documents for a given key. I'm not sure whether we can search by passing the key, as a query parameter, in the above url.

Please tell me know how to display the query results via the browser.

For example: get all documents where key="countryname".

Thanks.

Comment: The IP in the URL you are giving is not routable, thus other people won't be able to access it.

Comment: I just given my local machine ip and it won't be accessible. Please help me with your comments.

Comment: Your question is EXTREMELY unclear. Do you want to get ALL docs, by key, where the key is the countryname? Did you create a view for that? If yes, show us the code. If no, tell us if you know how view or couchdb works. We don't have a crystal ball... you know?

Comment: i have not created a view for the same, however wanted to search all the documents by the given key. could you please let me know how we can do it?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/tour.html)? Cause what you're asking is to reproduce large parts from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will not be able to query the database using  ..?testdata&key="countryname".

To query the database to get all documents where `key="countryname"`, you will have to first create a `view` in the database. See the CouchDB documentation at http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/intro.html.

I have provided an example below, if it helps:

Suppose your database contains the following documents:

```
{
  "_id": "708ae78bd79fa9802c827e03d3000fe3",
  "_rev": "1-f3408ffe54a9b9156dca5c9ad56ce396",
  "name": "AFGHANISTAN",
  "code": "AF"
}

{
  "_id": "708ae78bd79fa9802c827e03d3001767",
  "_rev": "1-9952b25ea39460b9923de505945efe3a",
  "name": "ALAND ISLANDS",
  "code": "AX"
}

{
  "_id": "708ae78bd79fa9802c827e03d30030a5",
  "_rev": "1-c1f3c9b2310f07f2985aa3fa363a281f",
  "name": "ALBANIA",
  "code": "AL"
}
```

Create a design document `"_design/countries"` with a view `"country"` in the database.

```
{
  "_id": "_design/countries",
  "_rev": "1-b30408713ded172df62502b45c959563",
  "views": {
    "country": {
      "map": "function(doc) {\n  emit(doc.name, null);\n}"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```

You can now query the database like this: `http://127.0.0.1:5984/countries/_design/countries/_view/country?key=%22ALBANIA%22&include_docs=true`

This will return you the document for Albania.

```
{
  "total_rows": 3,
  "offset": 2,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "708ae78bd79fa9802c827e03d30030a5",
      "key": "ALBANIA",
      "value": null,
      "doc": {
        "_id": "708ae78bd79fa9802c827e03d30030a5",
        "_rev": "1-c1f3c9b2310f07f2985aa3fa363a281f",
        "name": "ALBANIA",
        "code": "AL"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```